# Need program(prefer free) for edit csv google(google docs - like Excel) on desktop

Tags: windows, desktop, google-docs, cvs

In my website i have csv google(google docs - like Excel)) files that should contain word translation.

**I need desktop windows program for edit google(google docs - like Excel) on my computer desktop.**

Is the program exist? if not how can i edit google CSV on other ways?

Thanks

Comment: Worst-comes-to-worst, CSV is only a text format. You could use Notepad if you had to.

Comment: Google CSV is a service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/), it's free and able to parse CSV-files in both Writer and Calc.